# RGBA border transparency not visible with background colour

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a black border around the edge of my container, which should have an opacity of 15%. When adding the border property, the border appears inside of the container, not around the edge. I'm stuck as to why this is happening.

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 945px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
    margin: 15px auto 0;
}

.main {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #252525;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="content container">
    <div class="main">
               ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected result

[image]

Actual result

[image]

Comment: Don’t forget that the border will appear outside of the padding but within the margin.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you think this should display?  Do you expect whitespace between the border and content?  The padding will have the same color as the background.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Added images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `border` to `.container`.

Another way is set transparent background to `.container` and set `.main` `margin:2px`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the `background-clip` property:

```
.main {
   border: 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   border-style: solid;
   background: #252525;
   /* The background will not go behind the border */
   background-clip: padding-box;

    color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2KBPn/

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

Comment: The *right* option, and I don't think there's any difference in browser support between RGBA values and `background-clip` anyway.